# "ctrl" is coming as undefined in LINK in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have tried almost everything but "ctrl" is still undefined inside Link in directive. Please check. Help would be appreciated.

Error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined**

**My directive:**

```
myApp.directive("emailCheck", function(){

    return{

        restrict:"A",

        require:'ngModel',

        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$parser.unshift(function(viewValue)
            {
            console.log("asdf"+viewValue);
            alert(1);
            });
        }
        }

    });
```

**Html Part:** -- Tried both html parts shown below. Same result.

```
<input email-check="user.email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required/>
```

or

```
<input email-check type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required/>
```

Comment: The title of this question is wrong. "$parser" is undefined, not "ctrl".
If "ctrl" were undefined, the error you'd be getting would be:
 "TypeError: Cannot read property '$parser' of undefined"

Comment: Also, it's "$parsers", not "$parser".

Comment: Thanks @Hank. Yes I didn't see the title.
Error was due to mistake in $parser syntax. 
Thanks again. Wasted 1.5 hours on a silly mistake :)

Answer (score -4):

Link function don't have a fourth argument. from Angular's API documentation link takes a function with the following signature, `function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... }`

Comment: From the documentation near the bottom. `When a directive requires a controller, it receives that controller as the fourth argument of its link function.` but keep in mind **Best Practice** `use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link`